# Automatic Date Stamp on a Stage Change

Tags: formula, picklist, date, field-update

I want to add an automatic date stamp when an opportunity moves from Stage 1 to any other Stage that isn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Process Builder/Workflow Rule/Trigger to achieve this. Just create a custom Date/Time field, choose the appropriate method you want to use (e.g. Process Builder), define the action to fire when it meets your criteria (e.g. `ISCHANGED(StageName) && NOT(IsClosed)`), and use an action to set the Date/Time field.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on Field History Tracking for the Status field and that would log not only when it changed, but who did it as well as current and prior values.